# React with Redux-Saga - AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Trying to understand React with Redux-Saga. The problem faced is while trying to call an API. Though API URL is configured, however the application uses the same static data present in one of its own local `calendar.js` file.

What I am trying is to make use of APIs rather using the static hard coded data.

`api_helper.js`

```
import axios from "axios"
import accessToken from "./jwt-token-access/accessToken"

const token = accessToken

//url to get data is : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
const API_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
})
axiosApi.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token

axiosApi.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => Promise.reject(error)
)

export async function get(url, config = {}) {

  //the following does not work
  // return await axiosApi.get(`users`, { ...config }).then(response => response.data)

  return await axiosApi.get(url, { ...config }).then(response => response.data)
}
```

`url_helper.js`

```
export const GET_EVENTS = "/events"
```

`backend_helper.js`

```
import axios from "axios"
import { del, get, post, put } from "./api_helper"
import * as url from "./url_helper"

//Tried export const getEvents = () => get('/users')
export const getEvents = () => get(url.GET_EVENTS)
```

`saga.js`, The console.log(response) results in static content present in `calendar.js` file.

```
import {
  getEvents
} from "helpers/backend_helper"

function* fetchEvents() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getEvents)
    console.log(response)
    yield put(getEventsSuccess(response))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getEventsFail(error))
  }
}

function* calendarSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(GET_EVENTS, fetchEvents)
}
```

`index.js` The problem faced here is the dispatch method is not able to call the API rather it fetches the static content from `calendar.js`.

```
import {
  getEvents
} from "../../store/actions"

const Calender = props => {
  const { events, categories } = props

  useEffect(() => {
    const { onGetEvents } = props
    onGetEvents()
  }, [])

const mapStateToProps = ({ calendar }) => ({
  events: calendar.events,
  categories: calendar.categories,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onGetEvents: () => dispatch(getEvents())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calender)
```

`actions.js`

```
import {
  GET_EVENTS
} from "./actionTypes";

export const getEvents = () => ({
  type: GET_EVENTS,
});
```

`calendar.js`

```
const events = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Hey!",
    start: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1),
    className: "bg-warning text-white",
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: i don't see the code for your mapStateToProps . Also you can check in the redux dev tools whether the action is dispatched correctly and state is present in the store . If the state is present then you need to read the store value from mapStateToProps

Comment: @Shyam Yes I have updated my code and I noticed mapStateToProps is set to use the static data from calendar.js. May I know how do I allow it to make use of APIs rather using the calendar.js

Comment: Checkout @viet answer . You need to dispatch an action . But you are making a api call instead .

Comment: @Shyam I have dispatched an action only. As you can see the code above. I think the fixes has to be made on the mapStateToProps side.

Answer (score 1):

Your dispatch action is wrong. You may need to dispatch a redux action. So to make `redux-saga` listen your actions. You may try the following:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onGetEvents: () =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_EVENTS,
    }),
});
```

Comment: I have upadted my code above, the dispatch has no issues, The mapStateToProps has got an issue.

Comment: getEvents() is not an action .

Comment: getEvents() is  imported from ```action.js```. There it is configured with its TYPE. getEvents() is an Action Creator here.

Comment: What issue? Please show detail or ask another question

Comment: my bad i got confused because there are 2 get events in your code one in `actions.js` and the other in `backend_helper.js` .